# Can I stop my WCF generating ArrayOfString instead of string[] or List<string>

Tags: wcf

I am having a minor problem with WCF service proxies where the message contains `List<string>` as a parameter.

I am using the 'Add Service reference' in Visual Studio to generate a reference to my service.

```
   // portion of my web service message
   public List<SubscribeInfo> Subscribe { get; set; }
   public List<string> Unsubscribe { get; set; }
```

These are the generated properties on my `MsgIn` for one of my web methods.
You can see it used `ArrayOfString` when I am using `List<string>`, and the other takes `List<SubscribeInfo>` - which matches my original C# object above.

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
public System.Collections.Generic.List<DataAccess.MailingListWSReference.SubscribeInfo> Subscribe {
    get {
        return this.SubscribeField;
    }
    set {
        if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.SubscribeField, value) != true)) {
            this.SubscribeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Subscribe");
        }
    }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
publicDataAccess.MailingListWSReference.ArrayOfString Unsubscribe {
    get {
        return this.UnsubscribeField;
    }
    set {
        if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.UnsubscribeField, value) != true)) {
            this.UnsubscribeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Unsubscribe");
        }
    }
}
```

The ArrayOfString class generated looks like this. This is a class generated in my code - its not a .NET class. It actually generated me a class that inherits from List, but didn't have the 'decency' to create me any constructors.

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "3.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name="ArrayOfString", Namespace="http://www.example.com/", ItemName="string")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public class ArrayOfString : System.Collections.Generic.List<string> {
    }
```

The problem is that I often create my message like this :

```
client.UpdateMailingList(new UpdateMailingListMsgIn()
{
    Email = model.Email,
    Name = model.Name,
    Source = Request.Url.ToString(),
    Subscribe = subscribeTo.ToList(),
    Unsubscribe = unsubscribeFrom.ToList()
});
```

I really like the clean look this gives me.

Now for the actual problem :

I cant assign a `List<string>` to the `Unsubscribe` property which is an `ArrayOfString`  - even though it inherits from List. In fact I cant seem to find ANY way to assign it without extra statements.

I've tried the following :

- `new ArrayOfString(unsubscribeFrom.ToList())`  - this constructor doesn't exist :-(
- changing the type of the array used by the code generator   -  doesn't work - it always gives me ArrayOfString (!?)
- try to cast `List<string>` to `ArrayOfString`   - fails with 'unable to cast', even though it compiles just fine
- create `new ArrayOfString()` and then `AddRange(unsubscribeFrom.ToList())`   -  works, but I cant do it all in one statement
- create a conversion function `ToArrayOfString(List<string>)`, which works but isn't as clean as I want.

Its only doing this for string, which is annoying.

Am i missing something? Is there a way to tell it not to generate `ArrayOfString` - or some other trick to assign it ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22220989/475876

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any .NET object that implements a method named "Add" can be initialized just like arrays or dictionaries.

As ArrayOfString does implement an "Add" method, you can initialize it like this:

```
var a = new ArrayOfString { "string one", "string two" };
```

But, if you really want to initialize it based on another collection, you can write a extension method for that:

```
public static class U
{
    public static T To<T>(this IEnumerable<string> strings)
        where T : IList<string>, new()
    {
        var newList = new T();
        foreach (var s in strings)
            newList.Add(s);
        return newList;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
client.UpdateMailingList(new UpdateMailingListMsgIn()
{
    Email = model.Email,
    Name = model.Name,
    Source = Request.Url.ToString(),
    Subscribe = subscribeTo.ToList(),
    Unsubscribe = unsubscribeFrom.To<ArrayOfString>()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer not to return generic types across a service boundary in the first place. Instead return *Unsubscribe* as a `string[]`, and *SubscriptionInfo* as `SubscriptionInfo[]`. If necessary, an array can easily be converted to a generic list on the client, as follows:

```
Unsubscribe = new List<string>(unsubscribeFrom);
Subscribe = new List<SubscriptionInfo>(subscribeTo);
```

Answer (score 3):

Too late but can help people in the future...

Use the svcutil and explicitly inform the command line util that you want the proxy class to be serialized by the **XmlSerializer** and not the DataContractSerializer (default). Here's the sample:

**svcutil /out:c:\Path\Proxy.cs /config:c:\Path\Proxy.config /async /serializer:XmlSerializer /namespace:*,YourNamespace http://www.domain.com/service/serviceURL.asmx**

Note that the web service is an **ASP.NET web service** ok?!

Comment: Is this essentially the difference between a "service reference" and a "web reference"?  Does specifying service reference use the DataContractSerializer, and web reference use the XmlSerializer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS 2008 to consume service then there is an easy solution.

Click on the "Advanced..." button on the proxy dialog that is displayed when you add a Service Reference.  In the Collection Type drop down you can select System.Generic.List.  The methods returning List should now work properly.

(Hope this is what you were asking for, I'm a little tired and the question was a tad difficult for me to read.)

Comment: i'm tired too! i keep writing too long questions. sorry if it wasnt clear. i think you understood it though! unfortunately your suggestion doesn't work - it INSISTS on making a new ArrayOfString class for string whatever i choose 4 that! perhaps its getting confused thinking string is a value type?

Comment: hmm. i'd have to test it out. unfortunately my work schedule is a little hectic today