# Use/generate methods signatures with int[] insted of ArrayOfInt on .NET web service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services, service-reference

I have a ASP.NET web service (`.asmx`) with methods that receives `int` arrays (`int[]`) and nullable `int` arrays (`int?[]`) as parameters. I also have a test web application for consuming this web service via a Service Reference.

The problem is that every time I change something in the web service code, recompile it and update the service reference at the test application, a different type of parameter is generated for the web service methods on the test application. For example:

On the first build and service update, the method signature generated by Visual Studio at the test app is:

`void MyMethod(int[] firstParam, int?[] secondParam)`.

Then I make some changes, do it again and get something like:

`void MyMethod(ArrayOfInt fistParam, ArrayOfInt1 secondParam)`

(with `ArrayOfInt` being the equivalent of `int[]` and `ArrayOfInt1` being the equivalent of `int?[]`).

Once more, and I get:

`void MyMethod(ArrayOfInt1 firstParam, ArrayOfInt secondParam)`,

with `ArrayOfInt` and `ArrayOfInt1` swaped (`ArrayOfInt1` being now the equivalent of `int[]` and `ArrayOfInt` being the equivalent of `int?[]`).

What I really want is to use the simple `int[]` and `int?[]` types (no matter how many times I recompile and update the service reference!). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does no one ever found the reason for this? Does no one ever got annoyed with this silly behavior?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET (asmx) web services, or WCF?

Comment: Sounds like you should turn on WCF

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET, and I can't turn to WCF yet (for business reasons).

Comment: ...may this is simply impossible?...

Comment: Silly, but you can avoid by creating your own collection array class and using it in method as arguments, compiler won't interfere then.

Comment: Its doubtful you will return but could you post exactly what you get because your two examples are exactly the samething.

Comment: @Ramhound, why do you think that? In the first example, the method gets the desired signature. In the second one, the `int[]` type is replaced by the `ArrayOfInt` type, and the `int?[]` type is replaced by the `ArrayOfInt1` type, causing the code to break. In the third one, the `ArrayOfInt` type is replaced by the `ArrayOfInt1` type, and vice-versa, causing the code to break again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) tool to generate web service proxy instead using Visual Studio.

This work for me!

Comment: What makes you think this would solve his problem? Did you have this problem, then solved it by using wsdl.exe?

Comment: Yes, when I use wsdl.exe, I can use int[] instead ArrayOfInt().

Comment: It worked fine, but I was looking for a solution inside Visual Studio. If no one gives a solution for this, I'll accept this answer, for I think Visual Studio simply can't do this.

Comment: Well, I think there isn't a solution for this inside Visual Studio... so using wsdl.exe works fine as a workaround. Thanks all for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I just ran across the same issue. The difference for me was adding a web reference rather than a service reference.

Within VS, perform the following:

1. Right-click, select *Add > Service Reference*
2. Click the *Advanced* button in the lower left
3. Click the *Add Web Reference* button in the lower left
4. Add the URL and reference name then click *Add Reference*

My web reference properly added the method with `int[]` parameter.

**EDIT:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158270/189937) is a better answer with pretty pictures to illustrate!

**EDIT 2:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22220989/189937) gets rid of the `ArrayOfXXX` to `List<XXX>` silliness *and* doesn't use the legacy tech, so win-win as far as I am concerned. Now, how to do this within the tooling? Or is it *only* something you can do by editing the file directly?

Comment: Bad idea. Try specifying the type for collections in "Add Service Reference". It makes little sense to go back to using a legacy technology just to get `int[]` as a parameter type.

Comment: For my situation it already is an ASMX file, so not really "going backwards" - there is no back to go to. The OP also talks about it being an ASMX file. If I am not gaining the benefits of WCF I don't really see why I need to worry about it. If I needed more I wouldn't be using ASMX in the first place. :)

Comment: No, your _service_ is ASMX. That's no reason for the _client_ to be ASMX.

Comment: Yep, but there is no reason for my client to be WCF either. I don't need anything other than what ASMX offers and "just because" isn't a good enough reason. There aren't any performance issues I have to worry about that could maybe make WCF a better alternative, I don't have any security concerns that maybe WCF would make better, I don't have _any_ real reason that SOAP doesn't work perfectly well for me here. I am someone that **does** care for best practices, but there are also opportunities to not over-engineer for the sake of it - for me this is one of those times.

Comment: WCF would be using SOAP. FYI, the main reasons I would suggest are: 1) Lack of support from Microsoft for ASMX bug and security fixes, and 2) The ease of turning on WCF tracing when you want to know what's going on. It's just a config change.

Comment: Yeah, I get you. It really is just a matter of needs with this situation. It is an internal thing, rarely used and it works. If I have to revisit it at all I'd certainly reconsider, but as I said I don't feel the "benefits" do anything for me here. I have another similar situation right now with something else and getting it to work "the WCF way" is actually more of a bother - this too is just a small, pretty insignificant service. I'll learn a bit, so that is good, but it is more of a PITA right now than it is helpful - but it is the "right" way so I guess that makes it okay...