# InvalidCastException while Calling a Web Service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asmx

I always get a casting error when passing data from my application to my ASMX webservice

**My WebService code**

```
   Public Function SetAlterLogTrx(ByVal qsTrx As List(Of String)) As String
    Dim oStatus As New LogAlterStatusDsp

    Dim iRec As Integer = 0
    Using DBCONN As New SqlConnection()
        Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Conn").ConnectionString
        DBCONN.ConnectionString = sDBConnString

        If qsTrx.Count = 0 Then
            Return "Failed"
        Else
            Dim sQueryList As Array = qsTrx.ToArray
            For Each sQuery As String In sQueryList
                Using UpdateOutCommand As New SqlCommand(sQuery, DBCONN)
                    Try
                        With DBCONN
                            .Open()
                            iRec = UpdateOutCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            .Close()
                        End With
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Return "Failed"
                    End Try
                End Using
            Next
            Return "Ok"
        End If
    End Using

End Function
```

**My Client Code**

```
    dim qsArray() as string
    'This array has many lines
    Using oSvc As New AnfaEngine.AnfaWSSoapClient
        Dim svcReplay As AnfaEngine.LogAlterStatusDsp
        Dim oList As New List(Of String)
        oList.AddRange(qsArray.Cast(Of String).ToList)
        svcReplay = oSvc.SetAlterLogTrx(oList)
    End Using
```

and I always get this error message:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type 'WS.ArrayOfString'.

What should I do to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is this a legacy ASMX web service, or it it WCF?

Comment: It's ASMX web service

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my issue in the client code as follows:

```
 dim qsArray() as string
'This array has many lines
Using oSvc As New AnfaEngine.AnfaWSSoapClient
    Dim svcReplay As AnfaEngine.LogAlterStatusDsp
    Dim oList As New List(Of AnfaEngine.ArrayOfString)
    oList.AddRange(qsArray.Cast(Of String).ToList)
    svcReplay = oSvc.SetAlterLogTrx(oList)
End Using
```

Comment: Please consider explaining to others who land here the cause and solution, instead of just copying and pasting the working code without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you use "Add Service Reference" to reference the service, try using the "Advanced" tab to specify the use of a `List(Of T)` as the collection type.

If that doesn't work, then you'll simply have to send the service what it wants to receive.

Comment: I changed the collection type to be a System.Generic.Collection.list and the error still pops up

Comment: In that case, you'll just have to give it what it wants. What does `WS.ArrayOfString` look like? That's what you have to pass.

Comment: Honstly I don't know what "ArrayOFString" comes from, This is the funny thing :(

Comment: I did a search in my whole project and I did not find any footprint to a something called "ArrayOfString"

Comment: Did you look in Reference.vb?

Comment: John, I knew where the 'ArrayOfString' comes from, please review this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929735/can-i-stop-service-reference-generating-arrayofstring-instead-of-string