# Passing string array to webservice method

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, asmx

I have a web service with this method:

```
[WebMethod]
public int[] stringTest(string[] tString)
{

    int numberOfStrings = tString.Length;
    int[] returnS = new int[numberOfStrings];
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfStrings; i++)
    { 
        returnS[i] = 1;

    }
    return returnS;
}
```

And then I'm trying to pass an array of strings to it from a client program as following:

```
var client = new WebServiceSample.WebService1SoapClient();
string[] parameterNames = { "Windsensor","Temperature sensor"};
test = client.stringTest(parameterNames);
```

But I'm getting these errors:

> *The best overloaded method match for 'SoapWebServiceClient.WebServiceSample.WebService1SoapClient.stringTest(SoapWebServiceClient.WebServiceSample.ArrayOfString)'
>   has some invalid arguments*

and

> *Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to
>   'SoapWebServiceClient.WebServiceSample.ArrayOfString'*

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you include the complete error message?

Comment: Refresh web service reference.

Comment: Your error clearly says you should pass `SoapWebServiceClient.WebServiceSample.ArrayOfString` not `string[]`

Comment: Thanks for reply, how do i do that? how do connect SoapWebServiceClient.WebServiceSample.ArrayOfString to the array i defined parameterNames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SoapWebServiceClient.WebServiceSample.ArrayOfString arrString = SoapWebServiceClient.WebServiceSample.ArrayOfString();

arrString.AddRange(parameterNames);
```

or

```
arrString.Add(....); //if that exists
```

Check these links

- http://forums.silverlight.net/t/105441.aspx/1
- [Can I stop my WCF generating ArrayOfString instead of string[] or List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505943/can-i-stop-my-wcf-generating-arrayofstring-instead-of-string-or-liststring)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is:

In JavaScript build a new array:

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray.push([value1, value2,...]);
```

In C# just create an `ICollection` parameter to get your matrix:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public MyMethod[] GetMatrixFromJavascript(System.Collections.ICollection myArray)
{ 
   ... 
}
```