# Parametric WebServices

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamic, wsdl

I need to publish a webservice that take a variable number of parameters.
My problem is that the caller can send only simple parameters (primitive datatype) not xml, array or lists.

So i would like to dynamically generate wsdl so that if the caller try to access my webservice eg http://myendpoint:myport/baseWsName_numberOfParameter?wsdl then a wsdl with a customizable number of parameters is served (and the caller can use that versione of WebService), the parameters can be all of type strings in my scenario

I would like to avoid to manually define a huge number of overload one for any reasonable number of parameters.

Comment: You can pass an array as parameter.

Comment: what is the problem  with   for example  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" policyVersion="Policy15" />

Comment: @Reza absolutley no, as stated in the question, the caller does not support array but only simple parameters of primitives types.

Comment: @Skary  What kind of client can't support array as parameter? You can take a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991703/passing-string-array-to-webservice-method)

Comment: @Reza i work with a third party program (used by my customer) that can send parameters to any webservice, but only int, string or boolean. No array is supported and i would avoid strange thing like string concatenation (or CSV) for simulate array

Comment: @Skary If I understand your question correctly, IMHO using such dynamic webservice is more strange ;) and if the client can't pass array, using a comma separated string is a good option.

Comment: @Skary Also you may find this link useful: [Creating and exposing a SOAP service and its WSDL dynamically in C# (with a custom TCP listener!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549498/creating-and-exposing-a-soap-service-and-its-wsdl-dynamically-in-c-sharp-with-a)

Comment: @Reza that's really interesting, thanks i suppose i made something configurable in that way.

Comment: @Skary I posted an answer based on comments, to be more useful for future readers. Hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and if the client can't pass array, while using a comma separated string is a good option you can use [`AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs22fky4(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ServiceDescriptionReflector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.description.servicedescriptionreflector(v=vs.110).aspx) as used in [Creating and exposing a SOAP service and its WSDL dynamically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549498/creating-and-exposing-a-soap-service-and-its-wsdl-dynamically-in-c-sharp-with-a)

Comment: Thanks it seems a good idea, these day i try to implement it.
I'll let you know if it work as expected.