# How do you create a ArrayOfString for a WCF web service?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have a `List<string>` object that needs to be passed to a WCF web service.  The object type that the web service helper class wants is an `ArrayOfString` object.  For the life of me, I cannot find a way to convert my `List<string>` to an `ArrayOfString` object.

How can I do this?

**NOTE**

I have tried the following lines of code.  None of these conversions work.

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();

...

ArrayOfString strs = strList;
ArrayOfString strs = strList.ToArray();
ArrayOfString strs = strList.AsEnumerable();
```

What else can I try?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I stop my WCF generating ArrayOfString instead of string\[\] or List<string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505943/can-i-stop-my-wcf-generating-arrayofstring-instead-of-string-or-liststring)

Comment: What does the definition of `ArrayOfString` look like? Does it have a constructor? Base class? Does it implement any interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an instance of ArrayOfList, then copy your list into it like this:
`arrString.AddRange(strList);`

Answer (score 2):

I Created a web service with this method:

```
 public List<decimal> GetData(string[] ConnectionInfo)
```

The WSDL translation of those types were ArrayOfDecimal and ArrayOfString

So to receive the correct types in a client program, this was not sufficient:

```
 decimalArray = GetServiceClient.GetData(connectionArray);
```

To convert to ArrayOfDecimal and ArrayOfString, I found and instantiated the types through the service refence like so

```
GetWebService.ArrayOfString myStrArr = new GetWebService.ArrayOfString();
GetWebService.ArrayOfDecimal myDecArr = new GetWebService.ArrayOfDecimal();
```

Added the values to the new type:

```
myStrArr.AddRange(listOfConnections);
```

and succesfully called the method like so

```
myDecArr = GetServiceClient.GetData(myStrArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a web client using Jaxb and Wsdl file. The list parameters are typeof ArrayOfstring. There is no constructor for creating ArrayOfstring from List. So I get the string and add list elements. Here is my solution:

```
List<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
myArrayList.add("test1");
myArrayList.add("test2");

ArrayOfsring arrayOfstring = objectFactory.createArrayOfstring();
arrayOfstring.getString().addAll(myArrayList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works for C# but in Java you can create it in the following way:

```
 ArrayOfString myArrayOfString = new ArrayOfString();
 myArrayOfString.getString().addAll(Arrays.asList("your", "list", "of", "strings");
```