# How to use Array of Array of String

Tags: asp.net, arrays, web-services, jsp

Ok, I did a method in a Web Service on .NET and when a call the code in JSP I get
an ArrayOfArrayOfString and in the web service i returned a String[][] 
Now that I want the size of the ArrayOfArrayOfString, I can't. How can I convert the ArrayOfArrayOfString into a String[][] or how do I get the size of the ArrayOfArrayOfString
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

ArrayOfArrayOfString is ArrayOfString[], so it would be

```
ArrayOfString[] array;
int size = array.length()
```

Comment: No, it says: "incompatible types: ArrayOfArrayOfString cannot be converted to ArrayOfString[]" :(

Comment: it seems similar to this problem, also see the accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505943/can-i-stop-my-wcf-generating-arrayofstring-instead-of-string-or-liststring